# Mailchimp API v2

Tags: php, mailchimp

Could someone help me to show what i'm missing?

I would register subscribers by the PHP mailchimp API. I used this example https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples.

I copied the composer json file to get the API.
And, i used the lists controller to get info and push subscribers to mailchimp (ex : https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples/blob/master/Controller/ListsController.php)

```
try {

            $this->mc = new Mailchimp(Settings::get('mailchimp_api_key'));
            $lists = $this->mc->lists->getList();

            foreach ($lists['data'] as $list) {
                $this->mc->lists->subscribe(
                  $list['id'],
                  array(
                    'email' => $email
                  )
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Mailchimp_Error $e) {
            if ($e->getMessage()) {
                log_message('error', 'mailchimp : ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
            else {
                log_message('error', 'mailchimp : error');
            }
        }
```

Like this i would add subscribers to every lists i have on mailchimp.

On mailchimp interface, i got my api key (correspond to Settings::get('mailchimp_api_key') in code).
In mailchimp lists i added a "test" list (us8.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/).

But nothing happend.. Do you see what i'm missing?

Comment: Hi, just try this  $this->mc->lists->subscribe(list_id, array('email'=>'abc@example.com')); and check wither it subscribed to list or not .

Comment: Would you please post what error you face when you subscribed .. which you are logged in catch function .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailchimp has four flags, one flag is "double_optin" by default it is set to true. So when you subscribed the user to list the api return msg "Successfully subscribed" but when you check in list the user is not there in the list, for that you have to check the email and confirm user subscription for that list then user will appear to that list. So you will have to change the flag from "true" to "false".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have to confirm e-mail subscriptions from the e-mail that MailChimp sends out. Check those e-mails, including spam, so see if you at least got that.